# Tomcat 6 with broken manager app

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I'm using Tomcat 6.0.35 with Sun's Java 1.6.0_26 on Debian Sqeeze.

I have 2 apps: my app deployed at ROOT context and standard manager app.

After I accidently set **chmod 600 tomcat/conf/Catalina/**, manager stopped working with error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/webproxy/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml (Permission denied)
```

which is clear why.

But now I can't bring manager app back. I fixed file mode for Catalina folder, I deleted all tomcat's temporary files in conf/Catalina and work/Catalina, I restarted Tomcat many times, and I always get "404 - The requested resource (/manager/) is not available" error. There are no error messages in log files.

My app deployed at ROOT context works without any problems.

Is there any other place where Tomcat stores it's temporary files?

Do you have any ideas how to bring manager app back?

***Update*** Here are the related file listings:

```
$ ls -lh conf/Catalina/
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 webproxy webproxy 4.0K Dec 20 13:19 localhost

$ ls -lh webapps/
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x 5 webproxy webproxy 4.0K Nov 28 2011 manager
lrwxrwxrwx 1 webproxy webproxy   20 May 29 09:32 ROOT -> /home/webproxy/build –
```

Comment: Show out put for list(ls) on conf/Catalina and webapps directory.

Comment: $ ls -lh conf/Catalina/
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 webproxy webproxy 4.0K Dec 20 13:19 localhost

Comment: $ ls -lh webapps/
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x 5 webproxy webproxy 4.0K Nov 28  2011 manager
lrwxrwxrwx 1 webproxy webproxy   20 May 29 09:32 ROOT -> /home/webproxy/build

Comment: How about a full, deep file listing of conf/ including permissions? Also same listing for webapps/manager/META-INF/

Comment: Permissions were fine. After many assumptions I fixed this problem by deleting manager app and copying it from sources. Still don't know why it didn't work before.